# Magento order import export

Tags: csv, import, magento, export

Is there a way to import/export orders by CSV in Magento? I thought I could do this with profiles but if i try to create a new profile it makes me choose only between customers and products. I looked for an extension but i haven't found anything (anyway i'm looking for something free). Have you got some suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suggesting to use [Magento Order API](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#order_api), at least to get the information and then save it as csv at your own will. I dont think you can use the API to push data into Magento. You will have to create a custom module for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can import or export orders in the XLS format with [Import Export Orders](http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/import-export-orders.html) extension. It's not free, but it does what you need.